# Autoencoders with variable input size

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to develop an auto encoders for sounds that have a variable length between 0.05 s and 30 s. I'm wondering if there is the possibility to create a simple auto encoder that take in account this variable length as input or I should do some input preprocessing before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/denoising-autoenoders-with-variable-length-input

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer by commenting the other answer but for LSTM, the input size is just the size of your input at one given time step. I guess when you say you have a "variable input size", it's variable only on the time dimension. But your input dimension, other than the temporal dimension, should be fixed, and that's the dimension your LSTM want's to know as an input dimension. For example, as you're dealing with sound, it may be just the length of your FFT if that's your input, or another example, if you're dealing with midi piano roll, you can preprocessed your data so that each column of your input tensor is a time step, and each line is one of the 88 possible keys of your piano... there your input size is 88 and you'll input a tensor of size (num_of_time_step, 88)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conv1D or LSTM layers for variable-length time series data. You have to use global pooling to achieve a fixed dim later in the layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
ip = Input((None, 1))
conv1 = Conv1D(32, 3) (ip)
maxp = GlobalAveragePooling1D() (conv1)
final = Dense(10) (maxp)
model = Model(ip, final)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 1)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, None, 32)          128       
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d (Gl (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                330       
=================================================================
Total params: 458
Trainable params: 458
Non-trainable params: 0
```

- You have to either train with batch size = 1 or write a batch generator which generates batch with same length signals.

Comment: I actually don't get how to use the LSTM, I tried giving (None,None) as input shape but it doesn't work...